# Is it possible for Azure Function Topic Trigger to have trigger for multiple subscriber?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I have multiple subscribers for a topic and want to create Azure Function Trigger on Topic that will be triggered when any of subscriber receives message. Is it supported? If so, then how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Function Trigger does not operate on a topic level, rather queue or individual subscriptions. If you want to trigger a function on any message received by any of the subscribers, you'd need a catch-all subscription and a function trigger on that, or a subscription with a rule that would would encompass all other subscription conditions.